# Cors error when I'm trying to login (WebApi+Blazor)

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to create a login page in blazor that communicate with SOAP API, but when I try to add a communication service in the app return this error:

[image]

To solve this problem I have created a small APP to which I pass a username and password and it communicates with the API.

[image]

The app works fine but when I communicate it with Blazor is returning CORS error:
[image]

How can I solve it ?

My project consists of: client, server, shared.

Cliend side: Login.razor

```
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager Navigator
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;  


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 login_column">
        <div class="wrap-login100">
            <div class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    @if (@Navigator.BaseUri == "test2")
                    {
                        <img class="img-fluid login100-form-logo-src" src="imatges/logo/logo1.png" alt="logo">

                    }
                    else if (@Navigator.BaseUri == "test1")
                    {
                        <img class="img-fluid login100-form-logo-src" alt="logo">
                    }
                </span>
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <img class="img-fluid login100-form-logo-src" src="imatges/logo/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </span>
                <br>
                @Navigator.BaseUri
                <div id="div-login">
                    <div class="wrap-input100">
                        <input type="text" class="input100" @bind="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100">
                        <input type="password" class="input100" @bind="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="button-login" class="container-login100-form-btn text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" @onclick="LoginUser">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{   

    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
    private HttpClient Client
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                _client = new HttpClient();
            }
            return _client;
        }
    }

    private string username;
    private string password;

    public async Task LoginUser()
    {

        var result = await Client.GetStringAsync($"http://localhost:49220/api/login/ListUserInfo/{username}/{password}");
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result);
        var status = data.status;
        if (status == "success")
        {
            Navigator.NavigateTo("/index1", true);
        }
        else
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Error", "¡Usuario o contraseña incorrectos!");
        }
    }
}
```

Server Side: Startup.cs

```
using DVABlazor.Server.BlazorAccessesData;
using DVABlazor.Server.BlazorAuth;
using DVABlazor.Server.BlazorSoccerData;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;
using System.Linq;

namespace DVABlazor.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<blazor_soccerContext>(o =>
            o.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionBlazor_soccer")));

            services.AddDbContext<blazor_accessesContext>(o =>
            o.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionBlazor_accesses")));

            services.AddDbContext<blazor_authContext>(o =>
            o.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionBlazor_auth")));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddServerSideBlazor();       

          

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(); 

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried adding the cors policies but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

On your Startup.cs, add to the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsConfig",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                      });
});
```

And to the Configure method

```
app.UseCors("CorsConfig");
```

Comment: I already tried and the error persists. I do not know if it influences but the project consists of: client, server, shared

Comment: Can you post your whole Startup.cs?

Comment: Done, I removed the cors policy because it doesn't work.